# Nswag - specify order of controller names

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, nswag

.NET Web APi, .NET Framework 4.8, Nswag 12.3
Instead of random order of web api endpoints, or alphabetical - my customer would like them ordered in a specific order.
For example, the first thing a user does is Login.  So customer would like Login endpoint listed first.  Then Client endpoints, Disaster endpoints, Project endpoints, Disaster Client endpoints, etc.  So not alphabetical.

I saw this:
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2879
((In PostProcess you reorder the Paths collection of the document))

I started by putting the endpoint names in a list - in the order the customer wants them.  Then when document is generated - I create a new list of document.Paths - in the correct order.  I was going to set documents.Paths to my new list of paths but document.Paths is read only.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var orderedPaths = document.Paths.OrderBy(p => p.Key).ToArray();
document.Paths.Clear();
foreach (var p in orderedPaths)
{
    document.Paths.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
}
```